# Prove: $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln{x}\,\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt[3]{x(1-x^2)^2}}\stackrel{?}{=}-\frac18\left[\Gamma{\left(\frac13\right)}\right]^3$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, logarithms, special-functions, hypergeometric-function

I'd like to evaluate the following definite integral:

> $$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln{x}\,\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt[3]{x(1-x^2)^2}}\stackrel{?}{=}-\frac18\left[\Gamma{\left(\frac13\right)}\right]^3.$$

Preferably, I'd like to see this integral solved without the language of hypergeometric functions. This is integral is very similar to the one posed in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/883077/prove-large-int-01-frac-ln18xx2-3-1-x2-3-18x1-3dx-f), and the one in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/879854/prove-large-int-11-fracdx-sqrt394-sqrt5-x-left1-x2-right?rq=1). I believe the key to those two integrals is finding some appropriate cubic transformations that turns the integrals into a product of beta functions, but I kept running into problems. My hope is that if the simpler integral I posed above can be solved, the method of solution might be generalizable (in part or whole) towards the solutions of a broader class of integrals of cube-roots of polynomials.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We have:
$$ I = \frac{1}{4}\int_{0}^{1}z^{-2/3}(1-z)^{-2/3}\log z \,dz$$
hence:
$$ I =\frac{1}{4}\left. \frac{d}{d\alpha}\left(\int_{0}^{1}z^{-2/3+\alpha}(1-z)^{-2/3}\,dz\right) \right|_{\alpha=0}=\frac{\Gamma(1/3)}{4}\left.\frac{d}{d\alpha}\left(\frac{\Gamma(1/3+\alpha)}{\Gamma(2/3+\alpha)}\right)\right|_{\alpha=0}$$ 
and by using the identity $\Gamma' = \Gamma\cdot\frac{d}{dz}(\log \Gamma)=\Gamma\cdot\psi$ we have:
$$ \left.\frac{d}{d\alpha}\left(\frac{\Gamma(1/3+\alpha)}{\Gamma(2/3+\alpha)}\right)\right|_{\alpha=0}=\frac{\Gamma(1/3)}{\Gamma(2/3)}\left(\psi(1/3)-\psi(2/3)\right) $$
so:
$$\color{blue}{I = \frac{\Gamma(1/3)^3}{8}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{3}}{\pi}(\psi(1/3)-\psi(2/3))}$$
and the claim follows from the [reflection formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function) for the digamma function.

Comment: This is a nice answer, indeed ! Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I have not been able to get rid of hypergeometric functions and I apologize for that. What a CAS found is that $$\int\frac{\ln{x}\,\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt[3]{x(1-x^2)^2}}=\frac{\left(x \left(x^2-1\right)^2\right)^{2/3}}{\left(1-x^2\right)^{4/3}}A(x)$$ where $$A(x)=\frac{3}{2} \, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3};\frac{4}{3};x^2\right) \log
   (x)-\frac{9}{4} \,
   _3F_2\left(\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3};\frac{4}{3},\frac{4}{3};x^2\right)$$ So, $$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln{x}\,\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt[3]{x(1-x^2)^2}}=-\frac{\pi ^{3/2} \Gamma \left(\frac{7}{6}\right)}{2^{2/3} \Gamma
   \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)}=-\frac18\left[\Gamma{\left(\frac13\right)}\right]^3$$