# Could a transformation of a hyperelliptic integral related to cubic AGM be proved by substitution?

Tags: calculus, integration, elliptic-integrals

In this article [Arithmetic-Geometric Mean](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Arithmetic-GeometricMean.html) it is claimed that
let $\displaystyle
I_p(a,b)=\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{x^{p-2}\,\mathrm dx}{(x^p+a^p)^{1/p}(x^p+b^p)^{(p-1)/p}},\
M_1(a,b)=\frac{a+2b}3,\ M_2(a,b)=\sqrt[3]{\frac{a^2b+ab^2+b^3}3}$
then $I_3(a,b)=I_3(M_1(a,b),M_2(a,b))$.
In the source [Hypergeometric Analogues of the Arithmetic-Geometric Mean Iteration](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF01204654.pdf) the original proof involves differential equation. But I wonder if this identity can be proved directly by substitution as it is similar to Landen's transformation.
So my question is: Is it possible?

By the way, there is another identity that
let $I_3^\prime(a,b)=I_3(a,\sqrt[3]{a^3-b^3})$ then $I^\prime_3(M_1(a,b),M_2(a,b))=3I^\prime_3(a,b)$.

**Update: A possible approach**
The post [evaluate the integral...](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1900115/evaluate-the-integral-int-0-infty-fracdx-sqrtx3a3x3b3) suggests a relation between $I_3(a,b)$ and $\displaystyle
\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\mathrm dx}{\sqrt{x^6+p x^3+1}}
$. Using substitution $x=z\pm\sqrt{z^2-1}$ from [reciprocal square root of sixth degree polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/922957/indefinite-integral-typo-in-gradshte%C4%ADn-reciprocal-square-root-of-sixth-degree-p), the latter integral can be transformed to an elliptic one, namely $\displaystyle
\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\mathrm dx}{\sqrt{(x-1)(4x^3-3x+p/2)}}
$, which is easier to deal with.

**Related:**
If the integral were $\displaystyle
\int\frac{\mathrm dx}{(1-x^3)^{2/3}}
$, then the substitution $\displaystyle
x=\frac{-6z}{3\sqrt{4z^3-1/27}-1}$ from [Dixon elliptic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dixon_elliptic_functions#Weierstrass_elliptic_function) would transform it into $\displaystyle
\int\frac{\mathrm dz}{\sqrt{4z^3-1/27}}
$. Maybe we can do similar things to $I_3(a,b)$.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1190660/72031